# Deserializing JSON into object with HashMap using Jersey 2.2

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I've got following POJO:

```
public class Reservation {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> products;
    ...getters & setters for all fields....
}
```

and this simple Java Jersey REST resource:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String insert(Reservation re) {
    //do something here with ReservationEntity   
}
```

When I do a POST request with the following data:

```
{
  "name":"michal",
  "price":1234.3,
  "products":[
    {"id":1, "desc":"qwerty"},
    {"id":2, "desc":"ytrewq"}
  ]
}
```

I expect to get a object of class Reservation with list of products from the JSON data.
Howevere what I get is an object that only has name and price set. The ArrayList products is empty.

I tried to use org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper to deserialize the JSON data like this:

```
String data = "{\"name\":\"micha\".....}";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Reservation re = om.readValue(data, Reservation.class);
```

After this the object re had two entries (HashMaps) in ArrayList products as expected. I don't like to use the object mapper this way so I am asking, how to do it just with Jersey. I've read many articles on this issues, most of them advised to put  into web.xml like this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.foobar.rest.services;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>    
</init-param>
```

This didn't work for me either. I don't even have any  declaration in my web.xml

I am using:
- Glassfish 4.0
- Jersey 2.2

**EDIT:**
I've created a repository with a very simple project on GitHub:
[Jersey22](https://github.com/skmichi23/jersey22)
There are two POST methods in the MyResource class with paths: /working and /notworking

I'd appreciate any working example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried exactly your code in an old app of mine and I haven't faced any issue: the whole object is being deserialized without any problem:

```
@POST
@Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
public void getServices(Reservation reservation) {
    System.out.println(reservation.getName());
    System.out.println(reservation.getPrice());
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> products = reservation.getProducts();
    for(HashMap<String, Object> product : products) {
        System.out.println("Product:");
        for(Entry<String, Object> e : product.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue().toString());               
        }
    }
}
```

the result:

```
michal
1234.3
Product:
id - 1
desc - qwerty
Product:
id - 2
desc - ytrewq
```

so I cannot understand what is going wrong. In my app I've used Jersey 1.10 and Jackson 1.8.3, but I guess it will be fine with every version of Jersey and Jackson.

If I can suggest you an improvment, that could also maybe solve your issue, I would create a new object to define a "product"; conceptually it represents an object. Maybe a simpler `List<Product>` will be deserialized without any problem.

Comment: Thank you Enrichman, I tried with Jersey 1.17.1 and everything worked well.
I had to put this line:
<param-value>com.mycompany.jersey17;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
into <servlet> definition in web.xml. I tried to do the same with Jersey 2.2 but with no luck..

Comment: I also tried to use List<Product> as @Enrichman suggested - I've moved the HashMap into the Product class. After this list of Products was created, but the HashMap inside the product was still empty.

Comment: I was suggesting you the Product object to drop the HashMap and use just a simple id and description as field of the product, btw. I've downloaded your project, now I'm going to play with it a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it should work...

You can also try with [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) library, add it to your classpath and it should work without any other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got this working. I think important steps were:

- add jersey-media-json-jackson maven dependency
- register Jackson while creating the JAX-RS application by calling: register(JacksonFeature.class);